# How to use mod_rewrite to remove a part of a domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've this url:

```
example.com/de/type/villen/
```

It bothers me that my url contains the `/type/`. Is there an option to remove this string from my URL?

So someone goes to the URL `/de/type/villen` and NOT redirect to `/de/villen/`.
Only display in the browser `/de/villen/`.

Is that possible?

Comment: So you want to display `example.com/de/villen/` in browser but load the content from `example.com/de/type/villen/`?

Comment: Is `/de` and `/villen/` part static or dynamic?

Comment: Bit of an aside, but... you need to change the URL in your application as well, if you haven't already.

Comment: I can't change the URL in my app. It is a wordpress CMS with the theme wp-casa.

Comment: Ah ok, it's just that users will obviously still see the URL on the link and will experience an external redirect (2 requests) every time they click it.

Comment: Okay. That's not good. I think I have to come in love with my URL...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(de)/type/(villen)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(de)/(villen)/?$ $1/type/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I got only a redirect and that is not my purpose.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that? What happens when you enter `example.com/de/villen/` URL?

Comment: That means you have other rules or some cms framework in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/type/(.*) /$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: doesn't work for me.
For info. my domain is a subdomain. xy.example.com

Comment: where have you added this rule - in `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` ? What is happening once you have added it ?

Comment: I added the rule in my .htaccess. It doesn't do anything. The url /de/type/villen is still there.

Comment: Okay. We've to wait. I saw that I don't install mod_rewrite... But first. Lunch. I'll try it today and will write a comment.

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride` set for that domain, otherwise Apache will ignore the `.htaccess` file. You could test this by writing garbage into the `.htaccess` file and seeing if that gives an error?

Comment: Enjoy your lunch. Mine is hours away :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87357/discussion-between-cgee-and-monkeybrain).

Comment: This won't work - it's the wrong way round. You need to _externally redirect_ to the "pretty" URL (not _internally rewrite_) and then _internally rewrite_ back to the real/"ugly" URL.